# Making a sort by and load more system (NodeJS routes + MySQL)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, forms, ejs

I want to make a system that limits the number of posts that get displayed and a load more button that loads them from where the limit stoped previously WITH the capability to change the ordering of those same posts.

Right now I have:

html/ejs:

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
            <%
            if(results.lenght != 0){
                var i = 1;
                results.forEach(function(results){
            %>

            <div class="post">
                <div class="op"><%= results.username %></div>
                <h2 class="post-title"><%= results.title %></h2>
                <div class="content"><p class="post-content"><%= results.content %></p></div>
            </div>

            <% i++; }) %>
            <% } else { %>
                locals.message1 = 'No posts found :(';
            <% } %>
        </div>
        <div class="load-container"><a class="load" href="">Load more</a></div>
</main>
```

dropdown to select sorting:

```
<div class="drop">
    <button onclick="drop()" class="drop-btn">Sort by</button>
    <form id="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" formaction="/" value="1">Newest</button>
        <button type="submit" formaction="/" value="2">Oldest</button>
        <button type="submit" formaction="/" value="3">Popular</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

routes:

```
router.get('/', authController.isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {

  sql = 'SELECT posts.username, time, title, content, user_file, audio FROM posts JOIN user on posts.user_id = user.id';
  db.query(sql, function(err, results, fields){
    if(err) throw err;
    else if(results.length!=0){
      res.render('index', {
        user: results: results, time: moment.utc(new Date(results.time)).fromNow()
      });
    }
    else {
      res.render('index', {
        user: message: 'Sorry, we don\'t have any posts :(', message1: 'Very sad...', results: results
      });
    }
  })
});
```

I was thinking of having two variables in the route that would store the limit. Sort of like this:

```
var limit1: 0; // where to start displaying posts
var limit2: 8; // how many to display before stopping
// ADD 8 to both when button is clicked
var limit = 'LIMIT ' + limit1 + ', ' + limit2 + ';' //combining it for LIMIT in MySQL
db.query(sql + limit, function(err, results, fields)...
```

The problem is that I don't know how to keep track of how many I've already loaded and how to pass that data from the load more button in the EJS file to the router. The only way I currently know how to do is with a post form but I'm guessing that wouldn't be good at all.

For the sorting I would want to do basically the same thing:

```
// when new sorting is selected
var sorting = sorting; //selecting a sorting algorithm based on the button  clicked
// reset the limits when new sorting is selected
limit1 = 0; limit 2 = 8;
db.query(sql + sorting + limit, function(err, results, fields)...
```

But again I don't know how I would tell the route about the changes and how I would store the limits... I've tried some things but I couldn't get the variable from the EJS on button click to the route('/'... So if I only got one thing out of this I would want it to be the  variable passing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are brining back some results with the page load first correct?

With that assumption you have your main loop to display the posts

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
            <%
            if(results.lenght !== 0){
              results.forEach(results =>{
            %>

            <div class="post">
                <div class="op"><%= results.username %></div>
                <h2 class="post-title"><%= results.title %></h2>
                <div class="content"><p class="post-content"><%= results.content%>
            </p></div>
            </div>

            <%}) %>
            <% } else { %>
               No posts found :(
            <% } %>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="postCount" value="<%=results.length%>">
        <div class="load-container"><a class="load" href="">Load more</a></div>
</main>
```

(slight edits made to use arrow function, also not sure what the count was for? But its not really needed from what I can tell, if you needed the count you could always just use the length of the results as they would be the same.)

Now, you need an api route of some kind to pass the update variables to so you can make the request. It will be similar to the original route, so in the same route file you would have something like

```
router.get('/update/:sort/:start', authController.isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {

  // place relevent SQL code here that uses the passed params
  // then send back JSON object back to the browser

   res.json(jsonresponse)
});
```

So, in this sample, you would be passing the sort and start argument as part of an XHR/Fetch request, as you can see above, we have placed a hidden variable with the length of the original request so we know how many were returned, we will pass that as the 'start' value to the update endpoint and tell SQL to start at that record

**(Note, you could extend that route to have other limits passed etc, Also doing dynamic queries like this can open you up for a SQLinjection so you will need to sanities those before passing them to the SQL Query)**

From here you will have a change event handler on your page, that will listen for change events on the dropdown, from there you will take the value of that and pass that to an XHR request that hits the api endpoint with the passed variables, ones it returns the JSON object you will simply loop over it and append to the screen, once the loop is done, grab the total from the hidden object and add the total from the returned object so the next request knows where you left off (more for the load more option assuming)